# How to export point geomtery geojson from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson

I want export geojson (from shapefile), for leaflet project. But QGIS 2.6 exported geojson is multipoint geometry(leaflet doesn't read that), so its way to export point geometry geojson from QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: TY, I am using 2.6.0 Brigton

Comment: What is the Geometry type of your input data? is it also Multi point?

Comment: its point (i found it in layerproperties, metadata layer, geometry type of features in this layer, i am new in qgis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the qgis2leaf plugin. Here is an example (2 images below).

Here is an overlook on the plugin

[image: Plugin]

Here is the result. On the left is the webpage,which show the points. Also see on the right that datatype is points.

[image: Example]

You can download and install the plugin, using Qgis plugin manager, or from the [plugin page](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2leaf/). For further information you can either use the plugin's [GIT page](https://github.com/geolicious/qgis2leaf) or to follow a [short tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html).

Comment: Can you clarify in your answer how the plugin will aid in the conversion process and reading in multipart features (from shp to geojson)?

Comment: It's not clear from the OPs question that he is willing to use multi-point as input data; in addition he clearly stated that he has point data in the comments. It seemed to me that he was trying to export those to GEOJSON and it came out as multipoint, which (as mentioned) can't be read by leaflet. This answer shows that point can be exported as points, and not as multipoints; Yet if this is not what he was aiming for, I can suggest that it will be clarified and I can remove my answer, respectively.